# Unknown device on wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, mac-address, device-manager

I have a new unknown device with the name F4X0VG3 with a MAC address d4:54:8B:AD:17:90 showing up on my wifi network. How can I figure out what it is?

Comment: The MAC address is associated with a device with an Intel network adapter. Go through each device in your house and determine its MAC address

Comment: Use Advanced IP Scanner to scan your devices.  It usually gives you the name of the device along with the MAC address.

Comment: @John - The name of the device is F4X0VG3 which I suspect is an Intel equivalent of a RPi4

Comment: What OS? On Windows, I'd use Nirsoft's Wireless Net Watcher for more info, e.g., adapter type, user.text.

Answer (score 0):

Many mobile devices now typically randomise their MAC addresses on each connection to a WiFi AP for privacy purposes, unless you disable this in the connection's settings. You could always Wireshark the network and look to see whether that MAC address is associated with a DHCP transaction, if your network offers DHCP IPs.